# Get values of array based on binary string

Tags: typescript

```
fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "grape"]

dataBinary = "1010";
```

Since it's a `1` in index `0` and `2` of `dataBinary`, my fruits should be

```
myFruits = ["apple", "banana"]
```

What is the fastest way of doing it (performance wise)? Because I have to run it multiple  times with different `dataBinary` and fruits length is much greater

My attempt

```
  for (let i = 0; i < dataBinary.length; i++) {
    const j = parseInt(dataBinary[i]);

    if (j)
      if (data.colors.includes(colors[i])) {
        myFruits.push(id);
        break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Your code does not do what you specified in the text. It only adds the first match to myFruits due to the break. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it all in one line with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "grape"]

const dataBinary = "1010";

const myFruits = fruits.filter((fruit, i) => dataBinary[i] === "1");

console.log(myFruits);
```

You want to only keep fruits that have their respective index in `dataBinary` equal to 1.

I don't know what's up with the `data.colors` bit but you could also add that in using the `&&` (AND) operator to only get fruits that match both criteria:

```
const myFruits = fruits.filter((fruit, i) => dataBinary[i] === "1" && data.colors.includes(colors[i]));
```

Comment: If performance is the concern, you should definitely not call `Array.includes` inside the `filter`. Rather create a `Set` like this: `const colorSet = new Set(data.colors)` and then check `colorSet.has(colors[i])`. This has complexity O(1), while `Array.includes` has O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this assuming `fruits` and `dataBinary` have same length

```js
const fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "grape"];
const dataBinary = "1010";

const myFruits = [];
fruits.forEach((fruit, idx) => {
  if (parseInt(dataBinary.charAt(idx))) {
    myFruits.push(fruit);
  }
});

console.log(myFruits);
```